# how to open drupal login and signup form on modal form.

Tags: theming

I just want to open login form in modal box as per semantic ui framework http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html. I just want to use this framework. Is this possible with theming or custom module is require for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should include the necessary javascript in your theme .info file or template or module with drupal_add_js() , then you should use the code defined in the link you provide to target the element that you want to apply the functionality too. This elememnt may be generated by a module that specifies a theme function and uses a template (tpl.php) file in which you would put your markup.